# jruby annotation method not getting called

Tags: java, ruby, annotations, jruby

I have a jar named **test.jar** which contains following java classes:

**Test.java**

```
package test;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class Test {

public static void yoyo(Object o) {

    Method[] methods = o.getClass().getMethods();

    for (Method method : methods) {
        CanRun annos = method.getAnnotation(CanRun.class);
        if (annos != null) {
            try {
                method.invoke(o);            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and interface **CanRun.java**

```
package test;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CanRun {
}
```

and my ruby file is **Main.rb**

```
require 'java'
require 'test.jar'
java_import Java::test.Test

class Main
  def run
    Test.yoyo(Main.new)
  end

  java_annotation('CanRun')
  def onHi()
    puts "inside on Hi"
  end
end

app = Main.new
app.run
```

and I am running it by the following command:
jruby Main.rb

but there is no output.

Basically,what I am trying to do is, calling yoyo() of Test.java from Main.rb and passing object of Main in yoyo().then yoyo() in Test.java will analyze all the functions of Main.rb having annotation CanRun and if found will call them, in our case onHi should be called.
I checked that the object which I am passing in yoyo() is not null. The problem I am facing is that onHi is not getting called.

I tried a lot of things but nothing helped.

Am I using annotation properly in rb file or please suggest some other way.

Answer (score 1):

you annotation is not in the default package (nor is imported) thus instead :

`java_annotation 'test.CanRun'`

or

```
java_import "test.CanRun"
java_annotation :CanRun
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it didn't solve the problem. As the main cause of problem is the Main class object that I am passing to yoyo() function. In yoyo() function it is actually an object of org.jruby.RubyObject not Main class. try to getDeclaredMethods() of Object o in yoyo() function, they do not show methods of Main class.

Comment: well yeah, you need to `become_java!` before passing it to the Java side.
you should update the post since it's confusing that you asked a new q due progress ;(