# java_annotation removed after become_java

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, annotations, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have following piece of code

```
require 'java'
require 'jruby/core_ext'

class AnnoTest

  java_signature 'void run()'
  def run
    puts "inside run"
    cls = AnnoTest.become_java!
    puts cls.to_s

    cls.declared_methods.each do |method|
      puts "inside declared method loop"
      puts method.name
    end

    cls.annotations.each do |method|
      puts "inside annotation loop"
      puts method.name
    end
  end

  java_annotation 'CanRun'
  java_signature 'void onHello()'
  def onHello()
    puts "inside on Hello"
  end
end


fg=AnnoTest.new
fg.run
```

Output is showing all the declared methods but not annotated method.
How to get an instance of this class with annotations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jruby annotation method not getting called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468713/jruby-annotation-method-not-getting-called)